# GLSL - `out` in the argument

Tags: macos, glsl, metal

I am learning `GLSL` and `CG` now and come across this code:

```
float trace( vec3 origin, vec3 direction, out vec3 p ) //<-- What is "out"?
{
    float totalDistanceTraveled = 0.0;
    for( int i=0; i <64; ++i)
    {
        p = origin + direction * totalDistanceTraveled;
float distanceFromPointOnRayToClosestObjectInScene = map( p );
        totalDistanceTraveled += distanceFromPointOnRayToClosestObjectInScene;

        if( distanceFromPointOnRayToClosestObjectInScene < 0.0001 )
        {
            break;
        }

if( totalDistanceTraveled > 10000.0 )
        {
            totalDistanceTraveled = 0.0000;
            break;
        }
    }

    return totalDistanceTraveled;
}
```

I am converting these code into `shaders.metal` so that I can use with `Xcode`. But I am not sure what the `out` is and how to change it so that I can use this function in my shader in `Metal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `out` qualifier signifies that the value will be written to by the function. It's similar to (but not exactly like) pass-by-reference. The closest equivalent in Metal is a reference in the `thread` address space. An equivalent function declaration in Metal Shading Language looks like:

```
static float trace(float3 origin, float3 direction, thread float3 &p);
```

Comment: How different is it over `var p = ...`? it seems to me that will get the similar result in the code above. I believe it does have something that I still yet to understand. Please elaborate a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: After a bit of reading, is the `thread` send the value out to the thread for processing?

Comment: It's a way of returning multiple values from the function. Since you're returning the distance, and functions can only have one return value, "returning" the intersection point requires you to use a pass-by-reference variable.

Comment: The `thread` qualifier just signifies that the value you pass is local to the currently-executing thread, and that it doesn't live somewhere else, like threadgroup memory or device memory. All local variables in Metal are implicitly in the `thread` address space, much like the `auto` storage class in C++.

Comment: If I want to read more about this, What keyword should I google? Other than `out`, I found something like `inOut` too. I believe there are more. I look in the Metal Shader Language page by page but cannot find anything.

Comment: The "Parameters" section of [this page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)) provides a comprehensive description of these qualifiers. [This page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) has a decent discussion of passing output parameters by reference.